# How to avoid having to use @SuppressWarnings?

Tags: java, eclipse, weka, suppress-warnings

I am using an open source java library called [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) in an Eclipse Indigo project. The library seems a bit outdated so Eclipse is showing me thousands of warnings in regards to its code. A typical example is:

> ArrayList is a raw type. References to generic type ArrayList<E>
>   should be parameterized

In reference to a line like this:

```
ArrayList t = new ArrayList();
```

Eclipse's quick fix indicates that I can either convert the above code to use generics or that I can add a *@SuppressWarnings 'rawtypes'* annotation as a fix.

But both of these fixes involve making changes to the code of the open source project and I'd have to do these changes several (hundreds of?) times over.

Instead, might there be some global setting for Eclipse (or the Java compiler?) where I can indicate that I do not want to be warned for a specific project?

Comment: When I use google, I get ... http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fpreferences%2Fjava%2Fcompiler%2Fref-preferences-errors-warnings.htm

Comment: Thanks Brian. I've edited the question to reflect the fact that I'm not concerned about one warning message in particular - I'd like to avoid all of them for a specific project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been suggested that you just turn off the "offending" warnings via Window > Preferences, but that turns them off for all projects in your workspace, including the project(s) containing your own Java 1.5 + code.  That's a bad idea, 'cos you should be paying attention to the warnings if they occur in your code.  (If you ignore them you are liable to get unexpected runtime exceptions.)

Another possibility would be change the project settings to set the Java compiler's source level to Java 1.4 or earlier.  You should *only* do this on the Weka project.  The project containing your code needs to use a source level of at least Java 1.5 ... given that you are using generics.

---

> Thanks. Might this not cause problems later on when I deploy the project to a production server running JRE 1.6? Won't I have to have JRE 1.4 present there as well?

No ... for a couple of reasons:

- Unless you are modifying Weka, you can use the original JARs and ignore any build artifacts created by Eclipse.
- The source level and the target level are different.  The source level says what version of the Java language the source code must conform to.  The target level says what version of the classfile format should be used.  You can get the Java compiler to generate Java 1.6 bytecode format for Java 1.4 source code.  (But not vice versa).
- A Java 1.6 JRE will happily run a Java 1.4 JAR.

> Also, where do I do this? Do you mean Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level?

Yes.  Note that it allows you to specify the source and target levels independently ... modulo the constraint that the Java compilers only allow certain combinations.

Comment: +1, much better solution than switching off certain warnings in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks. Might this not cause problems later on when I deploy the project to a production server running JRE 1.6? Won't I have to have JRE 1.4 present there as well?

Comment: Also, where do I do this? Do you mean Project > Properties > Java Compiler > Compiler compliance level?

Comment: All my questions answered but... :) When I set the source level to 1.4 on the Weka project, I get a huge amount of errors. Any ideas why?

Answer (score 4):

Window > Preferences > Java > Compiler > Errors/Warnings > Generic Types. Alternatively this can be set on a project by project basis (if you have other projects in your workspace you want to keep the same) by right-clicking on the project > Properties > Java > Errors/Warnings > Check "Enable project specific settings" and then as before.

Answer (score 1):

Try Window->Preferences, Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings.  I see there's a "Generic types" section near the bottom.  I don't know if that's exactly what you're looking for, but from my experience this is a good place to ignore specific Eclipse warnings.

Comment: +1 but from my experience it is a good place to turn on more warnings.

Comment: Thanks. Definitely an option. Of course I need to click "Configure Project Specific Settings..." and choose my Weka project to work on. But the down side is that I have to go over a long list of different warning types and set each one to ignore. A but cumbersome.

Answer (score 1):

In Eclipse navigate to Window->Preferences->Java->Compiler->Errors/Warnings->Generic types here you will find a category for "Usage of raw type" which you can set to ignore rather than warning.